# LinqToSql Table not returning any object

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Can anyone explain why in my program:

```
linqToSqlDataContext.Scores.Where(x => Predicate(x))
```

returns no objects at all while:

```
linqToSqlDataContext.Scores.ToList().Where(x => x.Predicate(x))
```

returns exactly the right objects?

`Scores` is a `System.Data.Linq.Table<Score>`

Comment: What is Predicate supposed to do?

Comment: Predicate returns a boolean which indicates if the object should be selected.

Comment: Is Predicate translatable to SQL?

Comment: @PaultenBrink can you show the code of `Predicate`, i think should be IQueryable.

Comment: private bool Predicate(Score score)
{
    int? personTarget = null;

    return (score.PersonSource == 2) && (score.PersonTarget == personTarget);
}

Comment: I think the problem is in comparing the nullable int.

Answer (score 0):

Linq uses (by default) a [deferred execution model](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution).

Your first code is just a query. It is not executed. Whenever you iterate through it via (`foreach`, `for`, .`ToList()`, `.Count()`, `.Any()` etc.) that's when it will materialized.

Your second code calls `ToList()`, so your query is executed, but your `Where` does not any affect.

The correct way would be: `linqToSqlDataContext.Scores.Where(Predicate).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are right. On top of that the comparison of a Nullable<int> in LinqToSql has to be split into two comparisons: one for comparing with null and one for comparing the actual value. It would be nice if the compiler or other checker like ReSharper would give you a warning for this.

Comment: @PaultenBrink Glad to hear that you could overcome on this problem. Yep, the `Nullable<int>` is not really Linq2Sql friendly data-structure. If you have a fallback value then you can have a pretty nice expression in LINQ, like: `MyIntProperty ?? 42` and this can be translated into the following SQL out-of-box: `COALESCE([t0].[MyIntColumn], @p0)` where `@p0` is 42.